# Validate .bash_profile before loading?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc

Many command-line programs provide switches that allow you to validate a config file before loading it. ( For example, `nginx -c path/to/file -t` allows users to validate a config file located at `path/to/file` before attempting to start nginx with that file.

Is there a similar feature for `.bash_profile` in bash?

Comment: Maybe bash -n .bash_profile? Or name it something else until you're sure it's right.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I was thinking of maybe running it in a subshell / using the subshell as a sandbox environment. I wonder if there's a "correctly clean" way of doing that?

Comment: if it was me, I'd just start with your regular bash shell, edit a file named something else (like newprofile), and run ". newprofile" until I was happy with it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - In this case, I'm writing a setup script that will run unattended on the machines of other developers in my dev team. It sets up global npm packages they'll need to work on the project.

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the profile, then, and want to sanity-check it before pushing it out?

Comment: Our NPM setup requires a few global variables in the bash environment. I'm checking to see if those variables exist in the bash environment of the user who executes the script and--if they don't--appending their global declaration to the user's bash profile (so that they will exist in the future without running the script). The script will be doing this on the machines of junior developers who aren't very familiar with bash, however. So, my goal is to sandbox the changes the script makes and validate them before writing to the user's actual bash profile. Cut down on people coming to my desk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash has a [-n option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin) that will

> Read commands but do not execute them. This may be used to check a script for syntax errors.

It will output to stderr and set $? to 2 if there is a syntax problem. You could use it on .bash_profile like so:

```
bash -n .bash_profile
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
   # handle an error
fi
```

Based on the comment string, I can't help but add a suggestion for adding these global variables in a different way. Consider a somewhat-contrived case where the user's .bash_profile had a "return" at the end of it. Appending anything (like variable assignments) would be skipped by future bash invocations. Consider putting these global variables under /etc somewhere (such as /etc/profile.d, assuming that those files get sourced by your /etc/profile); that way, you can set them based on various shell syntaxes (csh, bash), and you don't have to check to see if they're set in the user's environments OR mess with their environment files.

Another alternative would be to put these global variable assignments into a custom /etc file of your choosing, and adding in code to the .bash_profile files to source that file if it exists. This has the same disadvantage of your current plan -- editing user's local files -- but added flexibility to use different global files for different users / scenarios.